# Why does moving a subcomponent of a Box consume the whole Box while moving a subcomponent of struct doesn't?

Tags: rust

Consider the following examples taken from [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/first-pop.html)

Example 1 [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5b37dd62632ea0ec94f8b9563f8817ce&version=undefined&mode=undefined)

```
pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
    match mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty) {
        Link::Empty => None,
        Link::More(boxed_node) => {
            let node = *boxed_node;
            self.head = node.next;
            //println!("{:?}", node); // Adding this line will induce the same error
            Some(node.elem)
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2 [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=69588dd6f8afea91ee36dedbe275d919&version=stable&mode=debug)

```
pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
    match mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty) {
        Link::Empty => None,
        Link::More(node) => {
            self.head = node.next;
            Some(node.elem)
        }
    }
}
```

Error from example 2

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `node`
  --> src/main.rs:42:20
   |
41 |                     self.head = node.next;
   |                                 --------- value moved here
42 |                     Some(node.elem)
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `node.next` has type `main::Link`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

With the following types

```
struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}
```

In example 1, the content of the `Box` (e.g. struct) is first moved to `node` then part of the struct is moved to `head`

In example 2, part of the `Box` is moved to `head`.

Why doesn't example 1 have the same compiler error as example 2? Specifically, if I move part of a struct why doesn't it consume the entire struct?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what types, and fields are present in the code. For example, you reference `self.head`, but nothing defines that. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*; Linking to code is fine, but it *needs to be in the question*.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to bind multiple fields of a boxed struct without getting “use moved value” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31391581/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.